# Connect jbutton to void class

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, event-listener

I wanted to connect **jcomp1** to the void class **somma**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "serial" })
public class Calcolatrice extends JPanel {
    private JButton jcomp1;

        public Calcolatrice() {
        //construct components
        jcomp1 = new JButton ("Somma");
    }

    void somma(){
        String val1 = jcomp5.getText();
        String val2 = jcomp6.getText();
        String sum = val1 + val2;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

And I tried with:

```
jcomp1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
  public void somma(ActionEvent e) { 
        String val1 = jcomp5.getText();
        String val2 = jcomp6.getText();
        String sum = val1 + val2;
        System.out.println(sum);
  } 
} );
```

But it doesn't seem to work...
Any ideas?
I just started coding and I thought this was an easy project but I'm already having troubles. For this reason could you explain as clear as possible please? Thank you.

Comment: Where did you put the last part of code you show ?

Comment: @Lyes here's the entire code: https://pastebin.com/SMphdPqZ

Comment: @GiovanniPoggi code, in the form of an [mre] should be posted in the forum with your question so we can see exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @camickr I tried but it kept saying it was too much code and too little words so I had to shorten it or it wouldn't let me publish the question

Comment: @GiovanniPoggi *so I had to shorten it* - exactly, that is the whole point of the [mre]. It forces you to shorten the code to only the code directly relevant to the problem. However, we still need to be able to compile/test the code to see the problem you are describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of how to create a basic java swing frame with an interactive button.

```
public class Win extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {

private JButton btn;
private JTextField  tf;
private JTextField  tf1;
private Label label;
private Panel panel;

public Win() {
    btn = new JButton("Click");
    tf = new JTextField("                   ");
    tf1 = new JTextField("                  ");
    label = new Label();
    label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,100));
    panel = new Panel();
    btn.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(btn);
    panel.add(tf);
    panel.add(tf1);
    panel.add(label);
    this.add(panel);
    this.setSize(500, 500);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    label.setText(tf.getText()+" "+tf1.getText());
    System.out.println("clicked");
}
}
```

You just need to instanciate the `win` class inside your main method.